# How to know the "lag"/delay of transfer over serial port?

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux

I'm currently working with 2 machines with linux, transfering data over serial communication and I would like to know if there's any way to know the delay/lag of the ports. For better understanding, when you ping a ip, you get lines like this

```
reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx bytes=xx time=xxms ttl=xx ....
```

What I'm seeking to get is the equivalence to `time` when you ping.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because its asking for a software or program recommendation. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to simply emulate the IP "ping".

Have your program on the other side respond to a special "ping" message. Then measure the time it takes between sending the original "ping" message and receiving the response.

However, this is mostly not needed. You have the speed of the communication (the "baud" rate) and can from that calculate how long it takes a message to be sent. Unless you have a very long cable the physical parts will most likely don't play a big role.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that part if possible, i'm looking for a faster way hehe

Comment: Aha, I knew about the baudrate but I thought that it is only how many bauds are transfered per second and that it would carry some delay to reach the other device. The current internet has also speed 10Mb/s,20 Mb/s....and it carries delays. On the other hand, internet needs to reach bigger distances than my 2 machines. So now I dont know till which point serial has delay or not...you confussed me :(

Comment: @Lomezno Delays on Internet is because of three things: Long distances for cabling; Processing times in switches and routers; And of course that the speed between two routers can be lower than expected. A short-distance serial communication interface doesn't have any of those problems. The speed you set is the speed it will have. Instead it's the programs on either side of the serial port that will introduce most delays, depending on what processing they do.

Comment: FYI the time delay between the last char of a message is received by U[S]ART off the wire and a **read()** syscall returns could range from 1 to 10 milliseconds. *"You have the speed of the communication (the "baud" rate) and can from that calculate how long it takes a message to be sent."* -- Actually that's only a minimum time.  There could be inter-character delays since it's asynchronous communications.    *"Unless you have a very long cable..."* -- Totally irrelevant consideration, since the signal travels at speed of light and RS-232 limits cable length.

Comment: *"Have your program on the other side respond to a special "ping" message."* -- Any receive + retransmit on the far end introduces an unknown time delay.  A loopback is all you need.